# Get functions mangled name from C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dllexport

I have function declared as `__declspec(dllexport) void TakeInput();`

The DLL which has this function is exported in C#.I am getting failure while executing function call to this function as entry point not found in c# code.

Googling shows that issue is with correct entry point is not provided.I will need to provide mangled name for this function.

So I would like to know how can I get mangled name of this function?

Comment: Use Dumpbin.exe /exports on your DLL to see the mangled name.

Answer (score 4):

in order to avoid name mangling, use `extern "C"`

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void TakeInput();
```

More reading: [Using extern to specify linkage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This will break if a different calling convention is specified on the command line (e.g. __stdcall or __fastcall).

Comment: @Frerich Raabe. One can explicitly set the calling convention in calling code

Answer (score 0):

You can use DependancyWalker (http://www.dependencywalker.com) or some other tool that lists DLL exports to get the mangled name if you really want to, but you're best doing what Armen suggested.

Comment: Don't forget that the mangled name is not stable across compilers.  It is also not stable across versions of the same compiler - the mangled name format has been known to change from one version ofthe compiler to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to compute the mangled name, I suggest to just export the unmangled name. Do do this, you need to do two things:

1. Disable C++ name mangling by using C linkage for your function You can do this by using [`extern "C"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
2. Ensure that your function is using the C calling convention. This is the default (at least with Microsoft Visual Studio) but this default can be changed using the [`/Gr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (which toggles the [`__fastcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) calling convention) and [`/Gz`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)  (which toggles the [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) calling convention) command line switches . You can enforce the C calling convention using [`__cdecl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like this:

So all in all, to ensure that your function is exported as `TakeInput`, use:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl TakeInput();
```

Comment: __fastcall is not implemented by the pinvoke marshaller.  Using global options is not great advice either.

Comment: @Hans: I didn't mean to advice using global options - I just wanted to point out that they may be used by the build system, so explicitely stating `__cdecl` may be necessary.